# Nexus One not recognized after 2.2 upgrade

Tags: android, adb

Using Mac OSX 10.6.4, device was recognized with the stock 2.1-update1 version.  Manually upgraded to 2.2 (FR91), and device is no longer recognized by adb.  Suggestions?

/Russ

Comment: You should try to ask on http://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure that you Dev settings are still on.
2) Change the USB wire

Comment: Dev settings are still on. I can mount the SD card. status bar shows "USB debugging connected" as well as "USB connected".  'adb shell' shows 'error: device not found'

Comment: Are your SDK up to date with 2.2. ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved here:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9437

requires rooting your phone to install an older version of the adbd daemon on your phone